# Plotting an exponential regression in ggplot2 using groups of data

Tags: r

I am a novice coder so this might be simple but i dont know what i am doing.

I have behavioral data from experimental animal work. Animals are recorded over 5 behavioral trials (HT, T1, T2, T3, T4) and the number of shocks they receive is reported. I have two groups of animals in this data set, an experimental group and a control group (TR and UT, respectively)

```
   cohort animalID trial num.shocks
1      TR   295727    HT        211
2      TR   295727    T1         20
3      TR   295727    T2         10
4      TR   295727    T3          4
5      TR   295727    T4          1
6      TR   295729    HT        161
7      TR   295729    T1         55
8      TR   295729    T2         56
9      TR   295729    T3         53
10     TR   295729    T4         53
11     TR   295731    HT        153
12     TR   295731    T1         19
13     TR   295731    T2          2
14     TR   295731    T3          0
15     TR   295731    T4          8
16     UT   295734    HT        197
17     UT   295734    T1        174
18     UT   295734    T2        155
19     UT   295734    T3        175
20     UT   295734    T4        155
21     UT   298736    HT        172
22     UT   298736    T1        178
23     UT   298736    T2        164
24     UT   298736    T3        133
25     UT   298736    T4        161
26     UT   298737    HT        168
27     UT   298737    T1        187
28     UT   298737    T2        119
29     UT   298737    T3        174
30     UT   298737    T4        155
31     TR   300844    HT        170
32     TR   300844    T1          4
33     TR   300844    T2          3
34     TR   300844    T3          0
35     TR   300844    T4          1
36     UT   300845    HT        167
37     UT   300845    T1        129
38     UT   300845    T2        123
39     UT   300845    T3        138
40     UT   300845    T4        127
41     UT   300846    HT        158
42     UT   300846    T1        158
43     UT   300846    T2        131
44     UT   300846    T3        125
45     UT   300846    T4        212
46     TR   300848    HT        131
47     TR   300848    T1         22
48     TR   300848    T2          3
49     TR   300848    T3          1
50     TR   300848    T4          3
51     UT   334953    HT        154
52     UT   334953    T1        203
53     UT   334953    T2        249
54     UT   334953    T3        263
55     UT   334953    T4        260
56     UT   334954    HT        229
57     UT   334954    T1        315
58     UT   334954    T2        285
59     UT   334954    T3        261
60     UT   334954    T4        209
61     TR   334955    HT        141
62     TR   334955    T1         11
63     TR   334955    T2          2
64     TR   334955    T3          1
65     TR   334955    T4          1
66     TR   334960    HT        206
67     TR   334960    T1        104
68     TR   334960    T2         86
69     TR   334960    T3         18
70     TR   334960    T4          8
71     UT   336414    HT        225
72     UT   336414    T1        155
73     UT   336414    T2        162
74     UT   336414    T3        184
75     UT   336414    T4        140
76     UT   336415    HT        223
77     UT   336415    T1        212
78     UT   336415    T2        141
79     UT   336415    T3        163
80     UT   336415    T4        151
81     TR   336416    HT        216
82     TR   336416    T1          8
83     TR   336416    T2         66
84     TR   336416    T3         39
85     TR   336416    T4         51
86     TR   336417    HT        197
87     TR   336417    T1         44
88     TR   336417    T3          9
89     TR   336417    T4          4
90     TR   339516    HT        158
91     TR   339516    T1         14
92     TR   339516    T2          2
93     TR   339516    T3          6
94     TR   339516    T4          2
95     TR   339517    HT        180
96     TR   339517    T1          9
97     TR   339517    T2          2
98     TR   339517    T3          2
99     TR   339517    T4          2
```

I have plot these data as geom_points grouped by cohort, with trial as the x axis and num.shocks as the y

I would like to fit an exponential model to these data to show that the TR group fits to an exponential decay while the UT group does not.

I have tried many different approaches using geom_smooth and different formulas or treatments of my data and I am getting numerous errors that I see no resolution to with my different methods.

Initially i thought that the issue was my x axis variable being categorical. But it can fucntion as a "time" variable and even when I make it a numerical value, I still have no success

this was my first attempt

```
ggplot(data = combo_behave_room[!(combo_behave_room$trial == "RT"),], 
             aes(x = trial, y = num.shocks, fill = cohort)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = expt.combo), color = "black", size = 3, position=position_dodge(width = .5)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group = cohort, color = cohort), size = 1, fun = mean, geom = "line")
```

but this is insufficient because i am looking for a regression model, not just a line plotting the means

i would like something as simple as this to work

```
ggplot(data = test[!(test$trial == "RT"),], 
             aes(x = as.numeric(trial), y = num.shocks, fill = cohort)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = expt.combo), color = "black", size = 3, position=position_dodge(width = .5)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", 
              formula=log(y) ~x)
```

but that also doesnt want to make a plot

finally, i tried to get chatGPT to help and i came across this functioning solution but it is insufficient because it required I scaled the y axis data first which means I am not plotting the absolute value of my data

```
ggplot(data = test[!(test$trial == "RT"),], 
               aes(x = trial, y = num.shocks_scaled, fill = cohort, group = cohort)) + 
       geom_point(aes(shape = expt.combo), color = "black", size = 3, position=position_dodge(width = .5)) + 
       geom_smooth(aes(color = cohort), method="glm", method.args=list(family="quasibinomial"), formula=y ~ x)
```

there are other layers on these plots to color the points or label the axes that i have excluded for simplicity

Comment: Hey. Please provide a reproducible example of your code.  do it by the commands dput (dput(name_of_data)) and copy the text in the console.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tricks you need:

- because your x-variable is categorical, you need `aes(group=cohort)` somewhere in your specification (your `as.numeric(trial)` would work as well, **if** `trial` has already been made into a factor — won't work if `trial` is a character vector — but this is a little bit prettier)
- use a Gaussian GLM with a log link
- use `y+1` as a response rather than `y` - otherwise the zero will mess you up (a log-Gaussian GLM is more robust than transforming the data, but still needs a little bit of help to get workable starting values)

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=16))
ggplot(dd, aes(trial, num.shocks)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = cohort)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "glm",
                aes(group=cohort, colour = cohort),
                formula = y+1 ~ x,
                method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = "log")))
```

[image]

While it may be possible to extract the regression information from the `ggplot` output, I usually find it easiest to re-run the model outside of ggplot.  The closest analogue to what `ggplot` is doing internally (i.e. running a separate model for each cohort, with trial as a numeric variable) is:

```r
dd$num_trial <- as.numeric(factor(dd$trial))
lme4::lmList((num.shocks + 1) ~ num_trial|cohort,
       family = gaussian(link = "log"),
       data = dd)
```

Comment: Ben, i cannot thank you enough! I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work! i am so appreciative! Thank you. One follow up, is it possible to extract the stats from these glm lines?

Comment: "Thank you" comments are actually deprecated on Stack Overflow (although the sentiment is appreciated); if the answer solved your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it. You can upvote it as well, if you like.